# How to rename row for a time series object in R

Tags: r, time-series

I have a data frame that I converted to a ts object, and while it retained the column names, for some reason it replaced the rownames with indicies instead.

the really bizarre thing is when I do `row.names(deaths.ts)` I get:

```
[1] "1980" "1981" "1982" "1983" "1984" "1985" "1986" "1987" "1988" "1989" "1990"
[12] "1991" "1992" "1993" "1994" "1995" "1996" "1997" "1998"
```

but actually trying to view the output gives:

```
Time Series:
Start = 1 
End = 19 
Frequency = 1 
    Jan  Feb  Mar  Apr  May  Jun  Jul  Aug  Sep  Oct  Nov  Dec
 1 1.22 1.37 1.24 1.40 1.47 1.45 1.56 1.51 1.36 1.47 1.44 1.39
 2 1.39 1.28 1.26 1.43 1.47 1.54 1.41 1.33 1.38 1.30 1.28 1.35
 3 1.20 1.21 1.18 1.36 1.30 1.34 1.25 1.28 1.23 1.21 1.13 1.25
 4 1.04 1.21 1.14 1.14 1.13 1.27 1.37 1.10 1.18 1.00 1.22 1.25
 5 1.08 1.21 1.20 1.15 1.16 1.25 1.26 1.34 1.30 1.09 1.17 1.24
 6 1.25 1.25 1.19 1.25 1.05 1.27 1.27 1.11 1.19 1.15 1.25 1.29
 7 1.11 1.28 1.25 1.26 1.19 1.28 1.38 1.42 1.38 1.20 1.09 1.13
 8 1.11 1.30 1.30 1.10 1.24 1.21 1.36 1.21 1.11 1.06 1.26 1.29
 9 1.05 1.22 1.29 1.34 1.18 1.35 1.36 1.25 1.19 1.11 1.22 1.37
10 1.20 1.28 1.16 1.26 1.26 1.40 1.27 1.26 1.27 1.25 1.27 1.31
11 1.13 1.38 1.23 1.45 1.33 1.58 1.52 1.41 1.40 1.21 1.13 1.26
12 1.13 1.24 1.33 1.44 1.58 1.45 1.54 1.50 1.43 1.29 1.27 1.36
13 1.29 1.22 1.37 1.46 1.47 1.51 1.52 1.34 1.31 1.47 1.29 1.38
14 1.18 1.38 1.42 1.53 1.47 1.65 1.51 1.43 1.55 1.37 1.38 1.40
15 1.35 1.34 1.28 1.31 1.32 1.38 1.45 1.35 1.43 1.26 1.26 1.22
16 1.11 1.17 1.20 1.19 1.22 1.37 1.46 1.29 1.38 1.23 1.09 1.15
17 1.03 0.97 1.04 1.07 1.05 1.18 0.99 1.14 0.93 0.98 0.95 1.02
18 0.93 1.03 0.90 0.95 0.89 1.10 1.01 0.95 1.07 0.89 0.90 0.97
19 0.79 0.79 0.86 0.89 0.78 0.78 0.97 0.70 0.80 0.78 0.81 0.81
```

So it *has* the correct row names in there, but shows indicies instead. Why would this be? Does this mean there's something wrong with how I converted the original data frame to a ts?

Comment: Please save your object via dput and write in your message, so that anyone will be able to reproduce it.

Comment: Try `print.default(deaths.ts)` - as far as I can tell, `ts` objects drop rownames during the conversion process. I'm not sure how you even got them in there in the first place. As @user31264 notes, some description of the code you used to generate the object would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

You have a multivariate time series, with each column being one month. Presumably you want a univariate time series, so you first need to convert your data frame into a numerical vector. If `deaths` is your original data.frame, then the following code should convert it:

```
deaths.ts <- ts(c(t(deaths)), frequency=12)
```